# Any good way to get the new Menlo font on Windows?

Tags: windows, macos, fonts

I like the new Menlo font on Snow Leopard a lot.  I tried copying it over to my Windows machine, but Windows does not like the format.  Does anyone know if there's any legitimate way of getting Menlo on Windows?

Comment: Is it an OpenType font or some other format?

Comment: To put that anther way, does the font file have an extension?

Comment: @alex, there's a new answer. the accepted anwer points at a _similar_ font, while the last answer links to the menlo ttf file. not sure if legitimate, though :-/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

this font https://github.com/andreberg/Meslo-Font is designed to be similar to Menlo

Comment: IMO, Meslo is far better on the eye than DejaVu Sans

Answer (score 33):

This may be a bit of a workaround - but the font is very similar to Bitstream Vera Sans Mono.

<s>[Here is a comparison](http://www.davidkaneda.com/post/123940811/menlo-font-macosx)</s> [(**updated link**)](http://9-bits.com/post/123940811/menlo-font-macosx) of Menlo and <s>Bitstream Vera Sans Mono</s> DejaVu Sans Mono (also based on Bitstream's original).

You can download the Bitstream set [absolutely free](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/ttf-bitstream-vera/1.10/ttf-bitstream-vera-1.10.zip) (zip file).

Comment: Actually, the site you link to compares Menlo and DejaVu Sans Mono. (It also notes that both Menlo and DejaVu Sans Mono are *based on* Bitstream Vera Sans Mono.) Still, +1 for reminding folks about these great open source fonts.

Comment: I find that the biggest weakness of Bitstream Vera Sans Mono or DejaVu Sans Mono compared to Menlo is that the minus sign symbol is too short. That's what I notice the most anyway. [Brutalist Mono](https://github.com/stlee42/Brutalist/releases/tag/2.2) is my favorite among the cousins of Menlo because it is most like Menlo including the longer minus sign symbol.

Answer (score 9):

I have found a github repo. Try here

https://github.com/hbin/top-programming-fonts

Hope this helps.. :)

Answer (score 4):

BTW, if you want to get any font from Mac over to your PC - just zip up the font(s) on the mac, and use CrossFont on PC to convert them. Done.

Comment: CrossFont doesn't handle ttc, and a lot of other types.

Comment: You have to use another tool such as [DfontSplitter](https://peter.upfold.org.uk/projects/dfontsplitter) to extract the .ttf files which are still somehow macOS specific and can't be installed in Windows. But you can convert those ttf files to the ones that will install under Windows using [CrossFont](https://www.acutesystems.com/scrcf.htm). My copy of Menlo Regular version 17.0d1e1 has 3157 glyphs. The FontForge method as well as OnlineFontConverter method would mysteriously reduce this number... But this CrossFont solution worked perfectly.

Comment: I got to the bottom of this. Using the ttx tool from fontTools project, I was able to find the difference. CrossFont duplicates cmap table with (platformID=0,encodingID=3) so there is another cmap table with (platformID=3,encodingID=1) and duplicates namerecords with (platformID=1,encodingID=0) into namerecords with (platformID=3,encodingID=1) with updated langID according to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/name#platform-encoding-and-language-ids). By doing this manually with ttx after splitting with DfontSplitter, I was able to convert with all free software.

Answer (score 3):

I split ttc into ttf files using FontForge and I installed Menlo font on Ubuntu.
It doesn't look exactly like on a Mac though. MacOS is better at font rendering.

Comment: Would you please upload it somewhere so I can use it? thanks in advance and Kind Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the file to a Windows format; you could try [DfontSplitter](http://peter.upfold.org.uk/projects/dfontsplitter) to do this. However, I'm not sure if this is legal.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 :

You can download **Menlo** font [here](https://github.com/hbin/top-programming-fonts/blob/master/Menlo-Regular.ttf) and click to open it.

When you open the font file, you can see **install button** on **left top side**.

Click that button and install it

or

Open search bar and write 'fonts' and drag and drop Menlo font file into the openned fonts folder.

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the original open source variant [DejaVu Sans](https://github.com/web-fonts/dejavu-sans) from the Web-Fonts project (also on [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dejavu-sans))

#### Comparison between *DejaVu Sans Mono* and *Apple Menlo*:

[image]

Comment: This duplicates Redandwhite's answer.

Comment: @fixer1234, I could be wrong, but I don't believe so.  The comparison picture is the same (and inlined), but the *where* is different.  This is the only answer here that points to the **web-fonts** project, which includes support for a lot of free typographies and seems to have a decent sized following.  Since the question is where can I get this font, I believe this is novel even though it uses the same font.

Answer (score 0):

I used [OnlineFontConverter](http://onlinefontconverter.com/) to convert the .ttc file to multiple .ttf files. There are of course copyright issues if you distribute the converted files, so please don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

`Hack` with modified `i` version is too similar to `Menlo`: https://github.com/ghsgz/a-custom-Hack-Font

Comment: Link only answer is useless. 
Can you elaborate on this a litle more?

Comment: Hah. So what should I do then ? Or you really believe that you can get Menlo like in MacOS with the same high quality on Windows ?
There is no better solution as mine.