# How to get the Monaco font for Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fonts

I'm interested in getting the following font, which is called Monaco. [This user](https://superuser.com/questions/561885/setting-monospaced-font-on-emacs?rq=1) says that it is Monaco, and so as confirmed by slhck.

[image]

But still I don't know where I can get this font (or something looks similar), and whether 
it is monospaced or not.

[Another person](https://superuser.com/questions/561885/setting-monospaced-font-on-emacs?rq=1) said that the `Monaco.ttf` was availble from http://usystem.googlecode.com/files/MONACO.TTF, but I tried it and it doesn't look the same.

Comment: It [actually is Monaco](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JtaY9.png). Font identification questions are off topic for this site, however if you have troubles getting the font to work on your system, please [edit] your question to ask for that problem instead, and please mention your OS and what programs you're trying to use it with.

Comment: Now it looks exactly like http://superuser.com/questions/59456/any-good-way-to-get-the-new-menlo-font-on-windows?rq=1, which is up-voted 22 times, except that mine has much more input and research.

Comment: Well, the other question is about Menlo, the font OS X replaced Monaco with after the release of Snow Leopard, so it's not the same. Maybe you can show us how the font looks like on your system – it might also just be a rendering issue. OS X has completely different font rendering techniques than you'll find on various Linux distributions. Both Menlo and Monaco are monospaced, by the way.

Comment: The `Monaco.ttf` from http://usystem.googlecode.com/files/MONACO.TTF looks like the `Liberation Mono`, or `Monospace` availble on my Ubuntu. So I deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The font linked to does match the font used in the sample. Slight differences in appearance can be explained by both font display settings as well as with the font renderer itself. You may need to play with those in order to get your text to exactly match the sample provided.